# Reduce weight for a binary Image

Tags: 2013-sp1, publishing, image

I want to reduce the weight of a binary Image Component when I publish it.

I've found a TBB called "Image Resizer" which resizes the binary Image based on a certain input parameters (Width, Height, Percentage and ItemName), but I don't need this. I need another way to reduce the weight of this Component. Is it possible?

I've been thinking about compressing the content of the Component but I do not think that works.

**[EDIT 1]**

My application doesn't uses DXA or DD4T TBBs in CM.

Comment: Is that your application uses DXA or DD4T TBBs in CM?

Comment: I have edit my question to add this information.

Comment: It's possible, then you need to write your own C#  Assembly to compress the output. by default, this functionality comes with DXA and DD4T Templates you can configure the template to compress the output of the page/component, it will be decompressed in presentation side.

Comment: I understand you are talking about compressing the content of the binary Component and put it into the package with the new content and remove the original Component, right?

Comment: For reducing KBs for images you have to do 2 things. First step in reducing image size is using the ImageResizer TBB to resize image to the right height/width constraints you want to use. The second step is to create/add a TBB that uses image compression. Depending on file types, there are .NET libs that can help you with that.

Comment: Can you **edit** your question and provide some more background/details as to why you need to reduce the weight of binaries while you publish? Because based on that information you could get different answers.

Comment: Yes. then you need to handle the presentation side also for the custom Binary Handler.

Comment: You could also consider using PNG only or something like that?

Comment: The comments show we're thinking about compression in different ways (reducing image size as in _png compression_ versus reducing package size even if the image is not viewable as in ZIPing a file). +1 to Bart's point for more details. It'll help to know if the problem is in editors uploading large files, in publishing large images, or website performance. And why don't you think compressing the "content" (binary?) works?